# How do I use @ExceptionHandler In spring to catch excptions

Tags: spring, exception

I need to find a way to catch exception and throw them to jsp pages

```
public class someController
    {
          @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
          @ResponseBody
          public void handleException(Exception exception,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
         {
            //how do I use this function to get exceptions and send them to
            //testModelView url below

         }

         @GET
         @Path("/testModelAndView")
         public ModelAndView resolveException()
         {

             ModelAndView mav = null;
             mav = new ModelAndView("/view.jsp");
             mav.addObject("/support/500.jsp", "Blah");

             return mav;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception handler method can have a return of ModelAndView.  similar to:

```
@ExceptionHandler(TAAException.class)
public ModelAndView handleMyException(Exception exception) {
    logger.fatal(exception);
     ModelAndView mav = null;
         mav = new ModelAndView("/view.jsp");
         mav.addObject("/support/500.jsp", "Blah");
         return mav;
    return modelAndView;
}
```